# How does it uninstall com.huawei.android.hwouc

Tags: package, adb, uninstallation

Upon adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 com.huawei.android.hwouc msg appears internal error uninstall not pss.

reason for uninstall: i do not need software update

where do i find the answer for not getting internal error

it tried adb shell... uninstall
result: internal error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.